# How to access Cache.addAll() request array

Tags: service-worker

Having a simple service worker updating, when receiving a message, as below. This works fine and the cache is updated. But next is to leave one of the files inaccessible and trying to get some notification that one is failing. How to list results of the requests?

Looking here
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll][1]

States
"The request objects created during retrieval become keys to the stored response operations."
 How is this interpretated? and in code accessed?

```
self.addEventListener('message',  event => {
  console.log('EventListener message ' + event.data);

 event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('minimal_sw').then(cache => {
       return cache.addAll(fileList).then(function(responseArray){
         console.log('EventListener responseArray ' + responseArray);
         self.skipWaiting();
       });
    })
  )
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earlier this year, the `addAll()` behavior was [changed](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/823) so that it will reject if any of the underlying requests return responses that do not have a `2xx` status code. This new behavior is implemented in the current version of all browsers that support the Cache Storage API.

So, if you want to detect when one (or more) of the requests fail, you can chain a `.catch()` to the end of your `addAll()` call.

But, to answer your question more generally, when you pass an array of strings to `addAll()`, they're [implicitly converted](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#cache-addAll-method) (section 6.4.4.4.1) to `Request` objects using all of the defaults implied by the `Request` constructor.

Those `Request` objects that are created are ephemeral, though, and aren't saved anywhere for use in the subsequent `then()`. If, for some reason, you really need the actual underlying `Request` object that was used to make the network request inside of the `then()`, you can explicitly construct an array of `Request` objects and pass that to `addAll()`:

```
var requests = urls.map(url => new Request(url));
caches.open('my-cache').then(cache => {
  return cache.addAll(requests).then(() => {
    // At this point, `cache` will be populated with `Response` objects,
    // and `requests` contains the `Request` objects that were used.
  }).catch(error => console.error(`Oops! ${error}`));
});
```

Of course, if you have a `Cache` object and want to get a list of the keys (which correspond to the request URLs), you can do that at any point via the [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys) method:

```
caches.open('my-cache')
  .then(cache => cache.keys())
  .then(keys => console.log(`All the keys: ${keys}`));
```

There's no need to keep a reference to the original `Request`s that were used to populate the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, cleared things up a lot.